# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<List<T>>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I am trying to write a generic cache utility using `sembast`. Follwoing is the code:

```
import 'package:sembast/sembast.dart';
import 'package:tachyon/core/domain/trait/map_serializer.dart';
class CachingController<T> {
  final Database _cache;
  final StoreRef<String, Map<String, dynamic>> _store =
      stringMapStoreFactory.store('objects');

  CachingController(this._cache);

  Future<void> insertObjects(
      MapSerializer mapSerializer, List<T> objectList) async {
    final objectMap =
        objectList.map((object) => mapSerializer.toMap(object)).toList();
    await _store.addAll(_cache, objectMap);
  }

  Future<List<T>> getObjects(MapSerializer mapSerializer) async {
    final finder = Finder(sortOrders: [SortOrder('phone_number')]);
    final records = await _store.find(_cache, finder: finder);
    final objectList =
        records.map((record) => mapSerializer.fromMap(record.value)).toList();
    return Future.value(objectList);
  }
}
```

The abstract `MapSerializer` class is:

```
abstract class MapSerializer<T> {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(T item);
  T fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}
```

But in the `getObjects` method of `CachingController<T>` I am getting this compiler error at the return statement.

```
The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<List<T>>?'.
```

which goes away if I change the return statement to `return Future.value(objectList as FutureOr<List<T>>?);` by adding casting but it doesn't seem to the correct way to do it.

I would love to have suggestion on what should be done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Future<List<T>> getObjects(MapSerializer<T> mapSerializer) async {
    final finder = Finder(sortOrders: [SortOrder('phone_number')]);
    final records = await _store.find(_cache, finder: finder);
    final objectList =
        records.map((record) => mapSerializer.fromMap(record.value)).toList();
    return Future.value(objectList);
  }
```

can you add `T` in the function argument `MapSerializer<T> mapSerializer` like this?